# WordPress 3 multisite - Grabbing another blogs menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a WordPress 3 Multisite setup with 2 sites. blog1 is the main site, and blog2 is a subdirectory of blog1.

I have created a menu in blog one that I can call using `wp_nav_menu`, now in blog2 I want to show that same menu linking to blog1. Is there a built in way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can import links from one blog to another.

http://en.support.wordpress.com/blogroll/import-export-links/

If this is not what you want, please clarify.

Comment: I am trying to access a custom MENU I created in blog1, and I want a dynamic link not import/export. As I change the menu on blog1 it should change on blog2 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this built into WordPress. What you can do, however, is create a page that show this menu on the first blog and then include it on the other blog by URL using `echo file_get_contents('http://www.firstblog.com/page');`